# jira python API get active Sprint

Tags: python, jira

I am using atlassian python API connector for writing script which can get the active sprint for the project.

API doc : https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/

In this API doc i am not able to find any method which can indicate whats the active sprint currently.

It is only having methods for creating sprint

```
 # Create sprint
jira.jira.create_sprint(sprint_name, origin_board_id,  start_datetime, end_datetime, goal)

# Rename sprint
jira.rename_sprint(sprint_id, name, start_date, end_date)

# Add/Move Issues to sprint
jira.add_issues_to_sprint(sprint_id, issues_list)
```

There is no such method to get the current active sprint.

Can anyone please tell whats the API signature to get the current active sprint.

Comment: The API documentation does not have a any method for to get current active sprint. But you can fetch all the sprint and then iterate over it and check start-date and end-date of each sprint to get active sprint.

Comment: can you please share example on how to get all sprint , i am not able to get any example of get_all_sprint

Comment: Please have a look at this 
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/api-group-board/#api-rest-agile-1-0-board-boardid-sprint-get

Comment: If you are using Jira CLOUD, use the v3 REST API [Get all sprints endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/api-group-board/#api-rest-agile-1-0-board-boardid-sprint-get), and supply the **state** parameter with the value 'active'.